# 2 Coverage maps Comparison (.tab files)

Tags: mapinfo, overlapping-features

I am trying to work out how much bigger is Coverage1 over Coverage2 in Mapinfo pro.

I have 2 Coverage data, Coverage1 and Coverage2.  Both maps are in .tab file format.  Coverage1 has a wider footprint than Coverage2.  Coverage1 and Coverage2 also overlaps in places.  I would also like to point out that, Coverage data is scattered.  I am looking to perform Spatial query to highlight the additional coverage provided by Coverage1, essentially (Coverage1 – Coverage2).

I am currently exploring the “Combine functionality” in Mapinfo pro as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using MapInfo's SQL functionality. The AreaOverlap function will give you the area of overlap between objects (using MapInfo's current default area units). If you use this in conjunction with the Sum() function you can get a total area of overlap between the 2 tables where their objects intersect.

[image]

It's now just a case of subtracting the resulting overlap area from the first table's total area and that will give you the difference.

Comment: This approach will work although I am yet to give it ago.  I will update this thread once I have adopted this method successfully.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the erase tool.  Set Coverage1 as the target and erase Coverage 2.  Then calculate the area of the resulting feature class to find how much bigger Coverage1 is.

More info about editing in MapInfo:  https://infogeoblog.wordpress.com/2012/08/20/advanced-editing/

Comment: I tried this method before posting here.  Somehow it did not work as I believe one of the coverage ought to be a closed vector or a poly line.